# Completing to 2 digits using list comprehension

Tags: python

I need to iterate a range between 0 to 18, but in case the number is smaller than 10 then it should contain 0 (e.g. 03) in the first digit, in order to fit the file name.

```
files = ["part_000"+i+".parquet" for i in range (0, 19)]
```

How do I add a condition inside the comprehensions so it would be part-00004 rather than part-0004 (04 instead of 4) etc.?

Comment: `[f"part_{i:04d}.parquet" for i in range (0, 19)]`

Comment: (Well, it would be `{i:05d}`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your code as follows:

```
files = [f"part_{i:05d}.parquet" for i in range (19)]
print(files)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

```py
files = ["part_000"+str(i).zfill(2)+".parquet" for i in range (0, 19)]
```

you are looking for `zfill()`.

EDIT: You can also just do

```py
"part_"+str(i).zfill(5)+".parquet"
```

Comment: That's the hard way.

Comment: That's a very complicated answer.  There are much simpler alternatives, as Olvin pointed out.

Comment: Right. Still my go-to way, since I can never remember the syntax for format specifiers with leading zeros.

Comment: Buddies, it's absolutely okay, internally formatting does exactly the same, so it could be an alternative, quite more complex though.